# How to draw a round rect border

Tags: codenameone

I have been trying to draw a round rectangle with a shadow, looked into `FloatingActionButton` and tried `RoundBorder' like this:

```
    Label labelXXX = new Label("XXX");
    labelXXX.getAllStyles().setBorder(RoundBorder.create().color(ColorUtil.WHITE).shadowY(0.0f).shadowOpacity(127));
```

But the resulting Border looks wrong.

[image]

According to the Javadoc of `com.codename1.ui.plaf.RoundBorder.shadowY(float)`I expected the shadow to be located at the top of the label. Also I expected the round border to fill the labels background and the shadow to be outside of the border.

What do I need to do to create a round rect border that fills the component space and has a shadow outside the component space?

Answer (score 0):

`RoundBorder` != `RoundRectBorder`. If you mean to use the latter it's a different class.

Notice that `RoundBorder` has a rectangle mode which you can activate using a method with the same name that will produce that result.

The shadow can be at the top when you set the Y to 1. Maybe the javadoc isn't clear. This is meant as a directional shadow so the light source is above hence the shadow would be below.